# Constructing abelian group from commutative monoid.

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, monoid, k-theory, topological-k-theory

Studying K-Theory and the construction of the group $K(M)$ there are some details that still remain unclear for me (I'm reading [Hatcher's book](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf) and [Karoubi's book](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~max.karoubi/K.book/MK.book.pdf)). First some background of the construction I'm using.

Let $(M, \cdot)$ be a commutative monoid. We define the abelian group $K(M)$ as the set of equivalence of classes
$$K(M):= M\times M\Big/\sim \;\;,$$
where $[(m,n)]\sim[(m',n')]$ iff there exists $c\in M$ such that $m\cdot n' \cdot c = m' \cdot n \cdot c$, with $m,n \in M$.

[Karoubi's book (pag. 52)](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~max.karoubi/K.book/MK.book.pdf) says "*the quotient monoid is a group*". However, I could not prove that $K(M)$ is a commutative group. Especially I do not see from where the existence of inverses come from? In my opinion, this could arise from the **universal property**:

*For any abelian group $G$, and any monoid homeomorphism $f: M\to G$, there is a unique group homeomorphism $\hat{f}: K(M) \to G$ such that the following diagram commutes*.

[image: Universal Property]

Since $G$ is an abelian group, and a homeomorphism maps inverses to inverses, then this could imply the existence of inverses in $K(M)$.

**Questions:**

1. How can I show clearly that $K(M)$ is an abelian group? (associativity, identity, commutativity, and *especially* inverses)
2. If this has a relation with the universal property, how could I know that such an abelian $G$ always exists such that it is homeomorph to $M$? And further, that this construction satisfies this universal property?

**Note:** I know that this construction $K(X)$ is used normally for the space of equivalence classes of vector bundles over a compact Hausdorff base space $X$. But let's keep it simple and general considering just $M$ to be any commutative monoid.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: As $\mathbb{Z}$ is the group completion of a commutative monoid $\mathbb{N}_0$ and an element $(m, n)$ represents $m - n$ in the usual sense, you should try to consider elements like $(0, n)$ for inverses for the general case, too.

Comment: 1) Write down the identity and inverse elements. Check directly that the definitions give you an associative, commutative group structure.